# Почему инстаграм не прогружается через webBrowser?

Tags: c#

Почему я не могу прогрузить в вебБраузере сайт? Делаю так:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://instagram.com/");
    while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

Происходит ошибка скрипта. Что можно сделать,чтоб прогрузить сайт?
Скрины ошибок:
http://cs628320.vk.me/v628320952/3f16d/yMvBGeRPWm8.jpg
http://cs628320.vk.me/v628320952/3f174/x_J4YEx21eU.jpg
http://cs628320.vk.me/v628320952/3f17b/3NEFZX27LsU.jpg

Comment: какой IE установлен в системе?

Comment: послежний, 11 версии

Comment: проверьте что выводит `webBrowser1.Version`?